# How can I access Amazon OpenSearch Cluster (deployed in VPC) from public securely

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, amazon-opensearch, opensearch-dashboards

We have deployed **Amazon OpenSearch cluster** in a custom **VPC**, **private subnets** (NAT only). When deployed OpenSearch in a VPC its Dashboard can't be accessed publicly.

What are the possible options that I can use to access the OpenSearch dashboard in a secure way?

**Using:**
Amazon OpenSearch v2.11 (latest)

I have reviewed several AWS documentation resources but am looking for something more intriguing.

https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/opensearch-dashboards-vpc-cognito

Comment: Did you try to proxy with NGINX with basic HTTP auth for example? You can also try use an SSH tunnel or VPN.